# Using ajax-jquery and fetch data using sql query.How to deal with response?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

**File1:test.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
 $.post( "test2.php")
 .done(function( data ) {
 alert(data);
 });
});
```

or
     var var1="something";
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $.post( "test2.php",{demo:var1})
     .done(function( data ) {
     alert(data);
     });
    });

**File2:test2.php**

```
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM xyz";
     $resultset=$database->query($sql);
     $found=$database->mysql_fetch_array($resultset);
     print_r($found); ?>
```

or

```
 `    $xyz=$_POST['demo'];
    <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM $xyz";
     $resultset=$database->query($sql);
     $found=$database->mysql_fetch_array($resultset);
     print_r($found); ?>`
```

SO,my test1.php  `alert(data);` will give alert a popup with some print_r array
like`Array(
        [0]=>1
        [name_id]=1
        )`
Something like that or whatever html code with be in test2.php it will fetch it and show

My problem is
1)How to get data in some json or xml or some method to parse this data efficiently?
2)If my test2.php content many queries then how get particular data for particular ajax $.post call?

Kindly suggest some genuine answers!!

Comment: Problem 1 is solved !!

Comment: (2) depends on your DB structure. Please provide a specific example to work on.

Answer (score 0):

```
use json_encode not print_r

<?php 
     $sql="SELECT * FROM xyz";
     $resultset=$database->query($sql);
     $found=$database->mysql_fetch_array($resultset);
     echo json_encode($found); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `print_r`:

```
echo json_encode($found);
```

Then, in JS, you will have to do an `ajax` request expecting a `JSON` object.